# Extract audio frames from AMR-NB file

Tags: java, audio, amr, 3gp

I wrote an algorithm to extract each frame from an AMR file. I considered the first 6 bytes of the file to be the header and the following information is audio frames. Each audio frame is composed by frame header and audio data. Frame header tells the frame's size in bytes (using CMR Mode table - http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AMR_format). The frame size is stored in the first byte of the frame -> second bit to 5-th bit, counting MSB as first bit.

The algorithm does not work and I decided to display on the screen each byte in binary way(0 and 1) and it appears that sometime the frame size number is greater than 7 and the CMR table has only  0...7 values.

Below is CMR table:

```
CMR      MODE        FRAME SIZE( in bytes )
0 AMR    4.75        13
1 AMR    5.15        14
2 AMR    5.9         16
3 AMR    6.7         18
4 AMR    7.4         20
5 AMR    7.95        21
6 AMR    10.2        27
7 AMR    12.2        32
```

and my output(each byte from amr file) is:

```
0 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3 -> 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
4 -> 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
5 -> 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
6 -> 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
7 -> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
8 -> 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
9 -> 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
10 -> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
11 -> 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
12 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
13 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
14 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
15 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
16 -> 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
17 -> 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
18 -> 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
19 -> 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
20 -> 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
21 -> 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 
22 -> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
23 -> 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
24 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
25 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
26 -> 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
27 -> 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
28 -> 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
29 -> 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
30 -> 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
31 -> 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
32 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
33 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
34 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
35 -> 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
36 -> 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
37 -> 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
38 -> 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
39 -> 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 
40 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I took byte nr 6:  10011110  -> 0011 is nr 3 and the coresponding CMR value for 3 is 18. I skip 18 bytes and I reach to byte nr. 6+18 = 24: 00000000 - CMR value for 0 is 13 and I skip another 13 bytes -> 24+13=37:  01101110 -> 1101 `is 13 WHICH ISN'T IN CMR table`

What I'm doing wrong? I suppose the printing in the binary way is correct. Below is the algorithm for reading each frame(not for displaying the binary way):

```
private void displayNrOfFrames() throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            long result = fis.skip(6);
            if(result != 6){
                throw new Exception("Could not skip first 6 bytes(header) of AMR.");
            }

            int number = 0;
            int bit = 0;
            byte b;
            BitSet bs;
            while((b = Integer.valueOf(fis.read()).byteValue()) != -1){     
                bs = Util.fromByte(b);          
                number = 0;
                //convert bits [1..4] to number
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                    bit = bs.get(i)? 1:0;
                    number += bit*Math.pow(2, 4 - i);                   
                }
                System.out.println(number);
                if(!CMR_MAP.containsKey(number)){
                    throw new Exception("Could not parse AMR file.");
                }
                //skip the number of bytes of this frame.
                fis.skip(CMR_MAP.get(number));

            }       

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`[EDIT]`

It appears that I'm doing wrong the conversion from byte to BitSet and then cause the algorithm to fail. At byte nr.6 it should be represented the number 121, but is represented by mistake the nr 158. Also the binary output is wrong since it use the same conversion. I didn't checked the conversion method(which I didn't posted here). Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: can you open your file in vim or any hex editor and see what it showing as file header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not too late with this reply.

First things first:
from the same [reference](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AMR_format)
you can see that the first 6 bytes (the file header) should be 0x23, 0x21, 0x41, 0x4D, 0x52, 0x0A. This is a constant value and should always be there. If it is not present then the file is probably corrupted and should not be used. So you should not blindly skip the first 6 bytes.

Now, AMR codec supports DTX (discontinuous transmission). DTX is nothing but a way of saving bandwidth by producing less data when vocoder detects silence. Your amr parser should be ready to expect DTX. For AMR-NB (amr narrow band or simply amr) DTX is signalled using mode 8. So your CMR Map should contain the below entry

> 8 AMR    SID        6  (SID is silence indicator...indicates that silence period is starting)

After SID, there will be actual silence frames which will be 1 byte in length (just the header...NO DATA), so you should have entry for

> 15 AMR    NO_DATA 1

Modes 9-11 should be discarded. And modes 12-14 are reserved for future use (generally these are also discarded). All the above information has been given keeping in mind that single channel AMR is being used.

In the prints you have pasted

> 6 -> 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0

This is supposed to be the AMR Toc header

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |F|  FT   |Q|P|P|
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

For storage, F bit should be 0 but in your example it is 1. And last two bits (which are padding bits) must be zero but in your example these are not 0. I believe your example is not telling the full story here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here was as you mentioned, I skipped blindly first 6 bytes WITHOUT verifying they really belong to AMR header. The amr file was instead a 3gp file. Now I managed to extract the raw amr from the .3gp and everything work ok. So do you suggest to extend the CMR table with 8 -> 6 bytes and 15 -> 1 byte?

Comment: and 9-11 should be discarded? If I have a 9 value I shouldn't skip any byte?

Comment: Yes sir...your logic should include mode 8 of size 6 bytes and mode 15 of size 1 byte. Generally I would skip all the modes from 9 to 14 as till now in my 4 years of working with AMR in real time scenarios I have not encountered a single frame having these modes.

Comment: If your file truly follows the AMR standard then you should not encounter 9-14 modes. Below lines from the AMR RFC
_The extra comfort noise frame types specified in table 1a in [2]
   (i.e., GSM-EFR CN, IS-641 CN, and PDC-EFR CN) MUST NOT be used in
   this payload format because the standardized AMR codec is only
   required to implement the general AMR SID frame type and not those
   that are native to the incorporated encodings._

Comment: We need the same thing now, does anyone have the complete code example to parse AMR files ?